# iOS 12 lock screen next song from HTML 5 web player

Tags: ios, html, html5-audio

In using a web based music player e.g. (https://sh0cked.github.io/deezer-vue/play/album/74434962) the song plays fine on lock screen screen but the controls (previous, next song) are not available. I wonder if there is a way to control these via HTML or is that only for apps ?

I also wonder if in HTML an image/album cover can be passed on to be displayed on iOS lock screen (on android it automatically displays the favicon )

Comment: Same question. Tried to see some popular sites with playlists (soundcloud, vk) — but there are no next/prev buttons too.

Comment: thank you @PeterSamokhin !  right well I I think is because the played on lockscreen was not meant to be for streamed audio but at least it works when the screen is locked. On android I see no forward or back buttons at all but it does play too